# Why is this function continuous in the proof of Folland's proposition 7.21

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, locally-compact-groups

Let $X$ and $Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Consider the following fragment from Folland's text "Real analysis", p226:

[image]

I checked the errata and the $\overline{U}\times \overline{V}$ in the definition of $F$ should be replaced by $U \times V$ (otherwise we have a problem because $\phi$ is not defined on the closure of $U$ and similarly for $\psi$).

Why is the function $F$ continuous and has support contained in $U \times V?$ I tried to apply the pasting lemma but I'm guessing I'm in desparate need of some coffee because I couldn't show it.

Comment: $F$ is contiuous as a product of continuous functions, as $G$ and $\phi \otimes \psi$ are continuous everywhere. Also the support of $F$ is contained in the support of $\psi \otimes \phi$ which is contained in $U\times V$

Comment: @alphaomega But the definition of $F$ is piecewise! I know that the product of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: It seems so but it is not. From the definition of $\psi$ and $\phi$ we have that $F$ is $0$ outside of $\bar{U} \times \overline{V}$

Comment: @alphaomega This is not by definition of $\psi$ and $\phi$ but by definition of $F$ itself?

Comment: It's clear that the support of $\phi \otimes \psi$ is contained in $U \times V$ by where $\phi, \psi$ come from. A fortiori this holds or $G$ too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure, but it should be contained in $U \times V$, not their closures.

Comment: But it is rather natural, since for example, $\psi$ is zero in $V\setminus \pi_{Y}(\text{supp}(f))$ and thus in a natural way, we can extend it continuously in all $Y$, by setting $\psi(y) = 0$, for all $y\in Y\setminus \bar{V}$. Another way to see it

Comment: $\phi \in C_c(U,[0,1])$ and ditto for $\psi$ and $V$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $F \mid_{U \times V}$ and $F \mid_{X \times Y \setminus U \times V}  = 0$ are continuous.

We know that $K = \text{supp}(\phi) \subset U$ and $L = \text{supp}(\psi) \subset V$ are compact. We claim that $\text{supp}(\phi \otimes \psi) \subset K \times L \subset U \times V$. In fact, $\{ (x,y) \in  U \times V \mid (\phi \otimes \psi)(x,y) = \phi(x)\psi(y) \ne 0 \} = \{ (x,y) \in  U \times V \mid  \phi(x) \ne 0, \psi(y) \ne 0 \}$ is contained in $K \times L$ and the claim follows because $K \times L$ is closed in $ U \times V$.

Since $F(x,y) \ne 0$ is possible only when $(x,y) \in U \times V$ and $(\phi \otimes \psi)(x,y) \ne 0$, we conclude $\text{supp}(F) \subset \text{supp}(\phi \otimes \psi) \subset K \times L \subset U \times V$. In particular $F$ has compact support which is contained in $U \times V$.

The sets $R = U \times V$ and $S = X \times Y\setminus K \times L$ form an open cover of $X \times Y$ and $F$ is continuous on both parts (in fact, $F = 0$ on $S$).  Therefore $F$ is continuous.